# What happened to dconf-tools in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: dpkg, dependencies

I created a `deb` package with the following dependency:

```
Depends: dconf-tools
```

I can install this package on Ubuntu 18.04, but not on Ubuntu 19.04 because there is no `dconf-tools` package on Ubuntu 19.04.

Is there a way to create a `deb` package supported both 18.04 and 19.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dconf-tools` was a transitional package to `dconf-cli` in Bionic Beaver (18.04). Try changing the package dependencies to:

```
Depends: dconf-cli
```